# Using char pointer in a function, get seg fault whenever trying to access first char of char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a program where I take text from a file and converting it into card hands for later evaluation.

This code takes in a line from a text file and parses the line by whitespace. Each time there is a whitespace, cardVal is updated with new value. When I try to access the first char of cardVal, cardVal[0], I get a segmentation fault in the function makeCard. However when printing cardVal[0] before passing to the function it gives the correct value. So my question is how can I access the a single char of a char pointer in the function makeCard. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "poker.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;  
    unsigned long len = 0; 
    unsigned long read;     
    char *line = NULL; 
    char * cardVal;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");           

    if(fp != NULL)
    {   //checks if files open
        while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
        { //gets a line
            cardVal = strtok(line, " "); //parses line 
            cardVal = line;

            while(cardVal != NULL)
            {   //parses line until NULL 
                printf("%c\n", cardVal[0]); //prints 1st char successfully
                cardVal = strtok(NULL, " ");        
            }           
        }
    }

    void makeCard(char * buff)
    {
        printf("%s\n", buff[0]); //!!!!SEG FAULT HERE!!!!
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Your code shown doesn't even call that `makeCard(...)` function.

Comment: Where are you calling `makeCard`? Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: In addition to `buff[0]` vs `buff`, the proper type for `len` is *not* unsigned long, but `size_t`!

Comment: Did you put the definition of `makeCard` inside your `main()` on purpose? If so can you explain why you would do that pls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, it is off-topic because it lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> printf("%s\n", buff[0]); //seg fault here
> ```

`"%s"` expects a `char*` as argument, but you pass a `char`. Use `"%c"` to print single `char`s.